# Is it possible to merge React and Vue build files?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, build

I know that React and Vue build files are a bunch of HTML, CSS, and JS.
So, what if I want some path (for example `/react`) is built with React
and another path (for example `/vue`) is built with Vue

Is it possible to do that?
I'm thinking of building with react/vue and put it on a directory (`/react` or `/vue`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using React.js and Vue.js Together in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56429109/using-react-js-and-vue-js-together-in-laravel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge Angular and Vue projects together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48691775/how-to-merge-angular-and-vue-projects-together)